# set and get properties on Shared Libraries

Tags: vb.net, dll, shared-libraries

i created a comp.dll for my project and then add the dll to my projects.sln (multiple projects), for every project on projects.sln i added comp.dll, and created 1 mdlmain.vb

```
Module mdlMain
    Public master_FA As New master_FixAsset
    Public objComp As New component.clsFunction
End Module
```

and 1 clsmain.vb to call main form on that project.

in comp.dll i made a property :

```
Private pubUserName as String    
    Public Property userName As String
        Get
            Return pubUserName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            pubUserName = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

i changed the properties through my login.vbproj (inside projects.sln), but when i tried to get the value of that properties (from fixasset.vbproj) it returns nothing. Is it because i declare `New component.clsFunction`in fixasset.vbproj so the compilers (?) create another new object in my .sln ? How can i fix this ?

Comment: Why did you give me that link ?

Comment: Sorry, posted to wrong tab/page/question